# How to dial a number in Iphone for India

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I want to dial a number from IPhone simulator for India. I have tried this on a button click:

```
-(void)makeaCall
{
NSURL *phoneNumber = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"tel:1-800-180-2222"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: phoneNumber];
}
```

But it's not showing any action of dialing any number.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't make a phone call from the simulator you will need a real phone for that.

but you can simulate an incoming call by selecting Hardware > Toggle In-Call Status Bar. also the incoming call should trigger in the app delegate the method applicationWillResignActive.

Comment: not even that because the simulator doesn't have that feature...not yet anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You might have to try that on a real phone, the simulator is a simulator after all and might not be able to make calls.

Comment: I should not have posted this as an answer since I don't really know as I've never tried it. It does not seem unreasonable that the iPhone Simulator would not be able to do this. Sorry mate.